# Notes in a business report without a verb?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

There are notes a in business report like 'Contractor to proceed as per the comments'. I really wonder that there is not verb to complete the sentence and apparently it looks to use as 'contractor will or shall proceed ~.' 
What does it make as a sentence? Also, can it apply for passive form (e.g. this to be proceeded by contractor.)?

Comment: Is ['*proceed*'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proceed) not a verb?

Comment: @Smock It's a verb, but it's in the infinitive form, so it can't normally head the predicate of a sentence.

Comment: @hamm: "proceed" is intransitive, so it can't be used in the passive (you don't proceed something, you just proceed - although you may proceed *with* something). But in general the passive can be used in this form of note - "Widgets to be deployed as discussed in the design meeting".

Comment: It's not formal running prose, so sentence structure isn't mandatory (if it ever is). Clarity must be preserved, of course. A 'to-do' list usually has self-directed imperative sentences:  • Buy bread / • Pick up laundry /  • Invade Poland (full stops usually omitted). Here, the agent is sensibly included, and the infinitive-marker added:  • Contractor to proceed as per the comments /  • Council to remove waste / ....

Answer (score 1):

In corporate offices, and also in government offices, this kind of instructions are common.  When it is, say, "go ahead", it is expected to be read as, "You are instructed to go ahead."

> Contractor to proceed as per the comments.

Here, it is addressed to an office person/subordinate/department to take steps such that "the contractor is advised to proceed"...

Comment: It seems to be omission of "is", which is quite common in notes or instructions: "(The) Contractor is to proceed as per the comments." would be a sentence.